# .NET API Controller returning 405 for AJAX POST

Tags: c#, .net, ajax

I have an issue with an API controller.

```
public class IssuesController : ApiController
    {
        private ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();


        [HttpGet]
        public IHttpActionResult GetNotes(int id)
        {
            Issue issue = db.Issues.Include("Notes").SingleOrDefault(m => m.Id == id);
            if (issue == null)
                return BadRequest();

            return Ok(issue);
        }


        //POST add DeveloperId to assign developer to issue
        [HttpPost]
        public IHttpActionResult AssignDeveloper(int IssueId, string DeveloperId)
        {
            if (IssueId == null || DeveloperId == null)
                return BadRequest();

            var issue = db.Issues.Find(IssueId);

            if (issue == null)
                return BadRequest();

            var projDev = db.ProjectDevelopers.Where(model => model.ProjectId == issue.ProjectId && model.DeveloperId == DeveloperId);

            if (projDev == null)
                return BadRequest();

            issue.DeveloperAssignedId = DeveloperId;
            issue.DateUpdated = DateTime.Today;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return Ok();
        }

    }
```

Here is the client side post

```
var formData = {
                    IssueId:  $("#Id").val(),
                    DeveloperId: $("#assignDeveloperSelect").val()

                };
$.post("/api/issues/", formData, function () {
                    $("#assignDeveloperSection").html($("#assignDeveloperSelect").find("option:selected").text());

                });
```

returns a 405 Bad Request Incorrect method type
Changing the URL to /api/issues/assigndeveloper returns 404 
using a GET at /api/issues/assigndeveloper/16 returns the get from GetNotes(16) 
I am already consuming the GetNotes method with 
`$.get("/api/projectdevelopers/" + projectId, function (data, status)`
I gave up on getting to work and moved this method to the non-API Issues controller and just returned a JSON ActionResult but I would like to move it back to the API controller.

Comment: Add the `[FromBody]` attribute to each of the Actions paramter's: `public IHttpActionResult AssignDeveloper([FromBody]int IssueId, [FromBody]string DeveloperId)`

Comment: @phuzi ExceptionMessage: "Can't bind multiple parameters ('IssueId' and 'DeveloperId') to the request's content. "ExceptionType: "System.InvalidOperationException"
StackTrace: "   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionBinding.ExecuteBindingAsync(HttpActionContext actionContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
 at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__5.MoveNext()
 End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)